# restorecon in CentOS does not follow fcontext order

Tags: linux, selinux

Experimenting with file contexts, I have faced a strange behaviour and it looks to me I'm missing something. Here's what I do:

Create a bunch of directories and files

```
# mkdir -p /virtual/www/cgi-bin
# touch /virtual/www/cgi-bin/script
# touch /virtual/www/webpage
```

Set up a couple of rules from scratch

```
# semanage fcontext -D
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/virtual/www/cgi-bin(/.*)?'
# semanage -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/virtual/www(/.*)?'
```

Test it!

```
# restorecon -vr /virtual
restorecon reset /virtual/www context unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
restorecon reset /virtual/www/cgi-bin context unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
restorecon reset /virtual/www/cgi-bin/script context unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
restorecon reset /virtual/www/webpage context unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

Despite the more specific rule for cgi-bin, every file/directory gets httpd_sys_content_t type. However, I want cgi-bin directory and below got httpd_sys_script_exec_t type. What am I doing wrong?

Tested in CentOS 6 and RedHat 7 with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Because patterns as used by selinux can't be sorted (e.g. compare `.*b` with `b.*`) selinux does not order the rules by specificness but by last-added-last-applied.

Unfortunately, semanage fcontext -l orders the rules by a simple string comparison, which helps to find your rule but not if you need to debug multiple matching rules.

You can see the the actually applied order in

```
cat /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
```

So you need to add the more general rule first and then the more specific. Or, even better, try your best to build the rules in a way, that only one rule per file could match.